# Android studio: How to receive Json Volley with different objects

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-json

According to this json file I want to receive data1 , xyz, abc object and their sub objects and show it in **recyclerview**.But I am receiving only data1 and their key-value pairs(index1 and name). I am using library **Volley**.
Can someone help me how to recive xyz and abc ?

```html
 {
"Data1":{
       "index1":"4",
       "name":"dan"
     },
"xyz":{
       "index1":"2",
       "name":"jimi"
     }
"abc":{
       "index1":"5",
       "name":"jordan"
     }
}
```

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("Data1");
getset1.seti(jsonObject.getString("index1"));
getset1.setn(jsonObject.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            JSONObject jsonobject=new JSONobject("");
                   for (int i=0;i<jsonobject.length();i++){
                       JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonobject.getJSONObject(i);

                              );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loop.As this is not an array so u have to fetch the all keys using iterator and then loop among them try this

```
Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

while (keys.hasNext())
{
    // Get the key
    String key = keys.next();

    // Get the value
    JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject(key);

    // parse inner string from value
}
```